# how to determine maven version of dependency used in specific phase

Tags: java, maven, command-line, dependencies, phase

how to determine which version of a jar I'm using during a specific phase?

is there a command in maven to check which version is being used of a specific JAR in a specific phase ? 
for example:

I was recently having an issue with

```
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
```

I had version 3.x running ok in compile time and runtime, but I had a specific dependency inside the project's dependency hierarchy overriding that version to version 2.3 specifically in test phase, I was able to see that using Eclipse's dependency hierarchy view but I wonder if there's a maven command or some way to print to standard output the specific version begin used a specific phase.

Comment: you can use maven enforcer plugin, and specify that for servlet-api only version 3.x is allowed

Comment: That sounds like you should use the dependencyConvergence rule of maven-enforcer plugin.

Comment: Furthermore check via `dependency:tree` which versions exactly used.